# Смена цвета Slider'а

Tags: unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

Как сделать смену цвета Fill (дочернего объекта Slider) в зависимости от `Slider.value` (0-1) чтобы менялся цвет условно от зеленого к красному?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[SerializeField] private Color _startColor;
[SerializeField] private Color _targetColor;
[SerializeField] private Image _fill;
[SerializeField] private Slider _slider;

//метод вызывается в тот момент, когда меняется значение слайдера
public void ChangeColor()
{
   _fill.color = Color.Lerp(_startColor, _targetColor, _slider.value / 
   _slider.maxValue);
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь оставлять немного более развернутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].